# Help with understanding $\int_C \frac{e^z-1}{z^4}dz$ = $\frac{\pi{i}}{12}$ where C is the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am referring to a solved example from Brown and Churchill's Complex variables and applications (ninth ed. page 231). If I simply use the Maclaurin series (which I think is a specific case of Laurent series), shouldn't the integral be $2\pi{i}*\frac{1}{3!}$ because the positive powers in the Laurent series are given by $$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi{i}}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$ In this case since the denominator is $z^4$ isn't $n=3$ and we can simply use the Maclaurin series expansion of $e^z-1$ and find the $a_3$ term which happens to be $\frac{1}{3!}$ This gives the answer as $\frac{\pi{i}}{3}$ but the answer in the book is $\frac{\pi{i}}{12}$ using the residue for $$\frac{e^z-1}{z^5}$$ at the point $z=0$

I am also not sure why the book calculates residue with the integrand with denominator $z^5$ in the solution. You can also look here at this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMROJ.png

[image: check this image]

Comment: Did you mean the residue for $\frac {e^z-1}{z^4}$, the integrand?  You put a $z^5$ in the denominator there...

Comment: Yes I mean z^4 but the book solves it by calculating the residue at z^5

Comment: Here is the image for the book http://i.imgur.com/xW2hJ4S.png

Comment: @Alan Any ideas why my method is incorrect?

Comment: From the residue theorem, it looks to me like your answer should be correct,  just from wikipedia.  So I'm not sure

Comment: Wait, I am not using the residue theorem, I am using the Laurent series expansion. It is the book using Residue theorem. Did you look at the image? Why the difference between the two solutions?

Comment: The book also uses the Laurent series ("The coefficient of $1/z$ in this last series..."). I think that the 4 is a typo.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thanks, can't believe I spent so much time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right !

$\oint_C f(z) dz= 2i\pi \sum_{a \in C} Res(f(z), a)$.

Here, $f(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z^4} = \frac1{z^3} + \frac1{2! z^2} + \frac1{3!z}+ \frac1{4!}+\ldots$

the residue in $z=0$ is $1/3! = 1/6$  so $\oint_C f(z) dz=\frac{2i\pi}{6} = \frac{i\pi}{3}$ and the response of the book is false.